# Вывод в поток данных при выполнении условий (использование тернарной операции)

Tags: c++, строки, stl, вывод, условия

Подскажите можно ли как-то записать в 1 строчку следующий код:

```
std::cout << "info: ";

if (isEq)
    std::cout << "value: " << value1 << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "data: " << data1 << std::endl;
```

На что-то подобное

```
std::cout << "info " << ((isEq) ? ("value: " << value1) : ("data: " << data1)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Можно, но это ухудшит читаемость кода

Comment: Пожалуйста, не указывайте в заголовках вопросов используемый ЯП. Для этого предназначены метки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, но не так - так у вас получается

```
("value: " << value1)
```

но оператор `<<` к строке неприменим.

А вот так - да:

```
std::cout << "info " << (isEq ? "value: " : "data: ")
    << (isEq ? value1 : data1) << std::endl;
```

Понятно, что типы `value1` и `data` должны быть совместимыми - например, `int` и `double` - будет выполнено приведение, как в арифметическом выражении. Если несовместимые - то вернитесь к своей первой (более понятной) записи.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Смотря **насколько** разные. Если одно приводится к другому - то вполне: https://ideone.com/cxZy5Z

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

```
std::cout << "info: " << (isEq ? ("value: " + std::to_string(value1)) : ("data: " + std::to_string(data1))) << std::endl;
```

Но мне кажется, читаемость получившегося кода намного хуже того, что приведено у вас :) .

Comment: Это работает только если `data1` и `value1` имеют арифметические типы...

Comment: Если это арифметические типы, то можно и так:    

    cout << (isEq ?"value: ": "data: ")    << value*isEq + data *(!isEq);